# How do I version Einstein Bots

Tags: liveagent, einstein

Einstein Bots can be versioned, so a new version can be worked on while the previous version keeps running (active bots can't be edited). How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I worked it out. The down arrow to the left of the Bot name lists all the versions, the one to the right of each version has a clone option.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone previous version